# Snap vertex selection box to grid

Tags: selection-tools

I would like the vertex selection box to snap to the grid, just like in gimp.

[image]

I this possible?

Comment: No. You can suggest it be added on [Right-Click Select](https://blender.community/c/rightclickselect/?sorting=hot) if you wish but don't expect it to be added for a year or so, if at all.

Comment: Because we're in 3D here, grid-points  do not normally form a rectangle in the view. Whatever proposal you thought of making would have to be simple and consistent across the application while accommodating that fact.